# Is it possible to use && operator in terminal command template loop?

Tags: shell, for, exit-status, control-flow

I wanted to make a list of similar clear commands clearer to read, so I've made a little terminal loop

```
for what in \
   cache \
   thumbs \
; do my template $what:clear; done
```

It works great, however I want to achieve an equivalent of

```
my template cache:clear && my template thumbs:clear
```

Is there a way how to easily and clearly put **&&** to work in such loop, ***without the complexity of adding if/else statement to the loop body checking for last command exit code and calling break if not 0?***

If condition is enaugh for you:

```
for what in \
   cache \
   thumbs \
; do
my template $what:clear;
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then break; fi \
; done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `set -e`:

```
(set -e;
for what in \
   cache \
   thumbs;
do my template $what:clear; done)
```

`set -e` causes the shell to exit when a command exits with a non-zero exit code, and the failure isn’t handled in some other way. In the above, the whole subshell exits if `my ...` fails, and the subshell’s exit code is the failed command’s exit code. This works in shell scripts and on the command line.

Another approach is to use a disjunction:

```
for what in \
   cache \
   thumbs; do
    my template $what:clear || break
done
```

This has the disadvantage of requiring `|| break` after every command, and of swallowing the exit code indicating failure; the `for` loop will exit with a zero exit code every time. You can avoid this by making `break` fail, which will cause the `for` loop to exit with an exit code of 1 (which is still not as good as the subshell approach above):

```
for what in \
   cache \
   thumbs; do
    my template $what:clear || break -1 2>/dev/null
done
```

(`break -1` causes `break` to exit with a non-zero exit code, and `2>/dev/null` throws away its error message).

As far as I know you can’t use `&&` to exit a loop, as in `&& done` or something similar.

Comment: @StephenKitt `&& done or something similar.` yes I was thinking exactly about something like that - something that would scream "I'm checking for every command exit code !"

Comment: @TobySpeight confirmed, that works (no `()` wrap = **terminal will close** :) ), it would be nice for others to have a little more description of this in the answer :) , however me personally - I will go with || break , since that seems like the clearest alternative to && (it would be nice to note that this simple `|| break` works as well and you dont have to redirect to devnull)

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way to exit a loop if an error occurs. The obvious way is to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, but that doesn't combine easily with iterating over a list. You'd need to assemble the list into a variable and then explicitly remove the elements from the list, which makes the code a lot more complex.

```
items=(cache thumbs);
while ((${#items[@]})) && my template "${items[0]}":clear; do shift items; done
((${#items[@]} == 0)) # to check if all the items were processed
```

A shorter way to write this than using an `if` statement is

```
for what in cache thumbs; do
  my template "$what":clear || break;
done
```

Using boolean operators is usually less readable than using `if`, but `somecommand || fallback` is fairly idiomatic.

Note that the `for` loop always succeeds. There's no convenient way to know whether the code exited early (you can test whether `$what` is the last item after the loop, but that requires having a convenient way to know what the last item was and it doesn't let you know whether the last item was processed successfully).

This doesn't scale well to multiple commands. You can instead turn on [errexit](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) mode with `set -e`. This causes the shell to exit as soon as a command fails (in simple cases — the details are rather complex, but it's enough here). Note that the whole (sub)shell exits, not just the containing loop or the containing function or the containing script. To exit just a part of the script, put that part in a [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping). Note that variable modifications don't survive the subshell.

```
( set -e;
  for what in cache thumbs; do
    my template "$what":clear;
  done
)
# Here $? is 0 if all the mv commands succeeded and nonzero otherwise
```